# how to render html response in angular 6 from a different domain

Tags: angular6, cross-domain, angular-httpclient

I am trying to Integrate AEM forms with Angular. I have my AEM forms url which will send the data in HTML and that HTML I have to render into Angular.

I am facing two issues :

1. The AEM site is hosted in different domain. So for that I added the header to stop cross domain issue and as the response I am getting is in html I have to set the response type as HTML. BY doing so the angular is able to render the HTML correctly but the the css and js are not loading properly as the response HTML has the the relative path of css and js.
2. As aforesaid I am using two extra parameter by build is failing by saying that only 1-2 parameter is expected in get.

**TS FILE**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-embeddedforms',
  templateUrl: './embeddedforms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./embeddedforms.component.css']
})
export class EmbeddedformsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  private url = 'http://localhost:4505/content/forms/af/formspoc/baggage-calculator.html';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url, {
      responseType: 'html'
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      document.getElementById('formdata').innerHTML = data;
    });
  }
}
```

**html CODE**

```html
<ul>embedded forms Start Here
    <li>Here we are trying to embedded the forms with angular </li>
</ul>

<div id="formdata"></div>
```

The expected result is that angular site should be able to embed the aem form with all it's css, js and functionality but this is not happening.

Comment: *"build is failing by saying that only 1-2 parameter is expected in get"* - it says that `headers` should be in the same object as `responseType`

Comment: @barbsan please find the error text:- ERROR in src/app/pages/embeddedforms/embeddedforms.component.ts(15,5): error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

Comment: 1. `this.url` 2. `{responseType: 'html'}` 3. `{headers: /*your headers*/}` and I told you to change this to: 1. `this.url` 2. `{responseType: 'html', headers: /*your headers*/}`

Comment: when i do that i will get the error: - ERROR in src/app/pages/embeddedforms/embeddedforms.component.ts(14,31): error TS2322: Type '"html"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: Take a look at [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#properties) `responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'` so `html` is not a valid value

Comment: So how i can render the HTML response i am getting form the external site without cross domain issue? If i change to the given format then the cross domain issue starts

Comment: If you face cross domain issues, you have to fix it on server side. If the issue is type `html`, you should propably set `responseType` to `text`, because MIME type is `text/html`